# How can I access an attachment downloaded from a URL in my code?

Tags: java, xml, servlets, xml-parsing, httpurlconnection

When I call in a servlet 1 a URL to servlet 2

```
URLConnection urlConnection = someURL.openConnection();
```

The response is an XML file attachment, with `Content-Disposition: attachment； filename=xxxx` `Content-Type:XML`

Now I would like to parse the attachment XML file, I've tried `BufferedReader bf = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReaderurlConnection .getInputStream()))`, but bf is null.

This makes sense because if I try to directly open the link in Chrome, it will automatically save this XML to my local disk, and response body is null. In Firefox and IE I have the chance to open it or save as, only when open in browser, the response will contain the XML file.

Can anyone enlighten me a bit?

Edit 1:
I tried to use curl but it seems it doesn't work with https.
Here is some more code:

```
URL qkrFileUrl = new URL(requestURL);

HttpURLConnection httpUrlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) qkrFileUrl
                .openConnection();
httpUrlConnection.setRequestProperty("Accept",
            "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8");
httpUrlConnection.setRequestProperty("Accept-Encoding",
                "gzip,deflate");
httpUrlConnection.setRequestProperty("Accept-Language:",
                "en-us,de-de;q=0.7,en;q=0.3");
httpUrlConnection.setRequestProperty("Connection:", "keep-alive");
httpUrlConnection.setRequestProperty("Host:",
                "connectionsww.demos.ibm.com");
httpUrlConnection.setRequestProperty("User-Agent",
                    Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:24.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/24.0");

httpUrlConnection.setAllowUserInteraction(false);
BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(
                new InputStreamReader(httpUrlConnection.getInputStream()));


        LOGGER.debug("bufferedReader Content is " + bufferedReader.toString());

        String line = null;
        String XMLFile = new String();
        while (bufferedReader.readLine() != null) {
            line = bufferedReader.readLine();
            LOGGER.debug("Line is " + line);
            XMLFile += line;
        }

        LOGGER.info("XML file from the qkr file is " + XMLFile);
```

and the XMLFile is null.

The request properties are the same as I make the request in Chrome.If I don't set the request Properties, I will get some strange javascript in my XMLFile:

> Error 500: java.net.MalformedURLException: no protocol:   if (self
>   != top) { try { // per Same Origin Policy, try to get top location
>   attributes, if (self.location.hostname != top.location.hostname) {
>   top.location=self.location; }catch(e){
>   document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].style.display = 'none'; }}
>   **iContainer_skip_init** = true;document.getElementsByTagName("html")[0].className+="
>   lotusui_ie lotusui_ie6";</script>document.getElementsByTagName("html")[0].className+="
>   lotusui_ie8";</script>
>
> Find out
>   more at ibm.com
>
> Try
>   the IBM Connections product documentation
>
> Welcome to IBM Connections 
>    User name:
>
> Password:  IBM    serviceName: "webresources",
>   contextRootEnabler: "/connections/resources",};var baseHost =
>   "connectionsww.demos.ibm.com";var needProxy = (baseHost !=
>   window.location.host || baseProtocol+":" != window.location.protocol);
>   isDebug: false, locale: "en-us", blankGif:
>   "https://connectionsww.demos.ibm.com/connections/resources/web/com.ibm.lconn.core.styles.oneui3/images/blank.gif?etag=20140502.131757",
>   proxy: "/connections/resources/ajaxProxy",}; base:
>   "https://connectionsww.demos.ibm.com/connections/resources", params:
>   "etag=20140502.131757&lang=en&country=US"CKEDITOR_BASEPATH =
>   window.CKEDITOR_BASEPATH ||
>   "https://connectionsww.demos.ibm.com/connections/resources/web/com.ibm.oneui.ckeditor/editor/";
>   
>   dojo.addOnLoad(function() { if (fragment) { fragment =
>   fragment.substring(1); input.value = input.value || fragment; try { if
>   (dojo.indexOf([_u, _p], document.activeElement) === -1) } catch (e) {}
>   var redirect =
>   findRedirectInFragment("/dm/atom/library/ECD7B321-7729-430F-9F5C-9279D83EF13E;D826C8CD-2B72-4546-82AF-A3D23377C061/document/%7BF2CA2079-F96F-4B3C-8B87-5CB0B616D743%7D/media/install.log.qkr","","");
>   function findRedirectInFragment(redirect, base, query) { if (hash) {
>   if (hash.length > 0) { hash = hash.substring(1); if (queryMarker !=
>   -1) { hash = hash.substring(0,queryMarker); if (hash.charAt(0) == "/" && base.charAt(base.length-1) == "/") base += hash; } return redirect;
>   null

Comment: Have you tried `urlConnection.getContent()` or `urlConnection.getContent(byte[] bytes) `? http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/net/URLConnection.html

Comment: @developerwjk Thanks for your reply. using urlConnection.getContent() results in "sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection$HttpInputStream@59eed81b". Really strange what urlConnection actually got when the response is an attachment.

Comment: Would you be opposed to adding another library, and trying to open the connection and entity? e.g. HttpEntity httpEntity = getEntity(url); InputStream stream = httpEntity.getContent(), then process your stream...

Comment: `Content-Disposition` header is only meta-info and not really import when you just want to parse the XML. Show us more of your code and/or have a look at some examples.

Comment: @hgoebl I've added more info in Edit 1.